# appsettings.json in .netCore console application

Tags: json, .net-core, appsettings

I have an appsettings.json file with the following values

```
{ 
  "MailOptions": 
  { 
    "Username": "ruskin", 
    "Password": "password" 
  } 
}
```

When I read it via the `ConfigurationBuilder` I can only access the values via `configuration["MailSettings:Username"]`. I want to grab the entire MailOptions string, is there anyway to do that? I don't want to use Json to parse the file etc...I want to stick to configuration builder.

I would expect `configuration.GetSection("MailOptions")` to work? It simply returns `null`.

**What I have tried**

```
SomeSection aSection = new SomeSection();
ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.Configure<SomeSection>(options => configuration.GetSection("SomeSection").Bind(aSection));
var someSection = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<SomeSection>>();

// aSection is instantiated but no values in it
// someSection is null
```

My appsettings.json

```
{
  "SomeSection": {
    "UserName": "ruskin",
    "Password": "dantra" 
  }
}
```

And my POCO class

```
public class SomeSection
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This nice article about `Strongly Typed Configuration Settings in ASP.NET Core` provides the clear example of how to work with settings in .NET Core https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration framework is an abstraction over the underlying source types. So `MailOptions:Username` could come from JSON, an environment variables or even INI files - and the configuration system can even be configured with multiple sources. If need a JSON string to configure your mail library and want to use the configuration abstraction, I suggest creating a class to hold the settings and serialize it to a JSON string again.

EDIT:

Using `configuration.GetSection("SomeSection").Get<SomeSection>()` I can successfully get the POCO from the app. see [sample application](https://github.com/dasMulli/so-config-example).

Comment: Sorry that doesn't quite make sense, I have tried all of that, my main problem is that I can access individual values within the `appsettings.json` but I can't serialize it to a class even when I have a POCO to serialize into...maybe a code example? This is just a .netcore console application, not a web app btw

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I have added more information

Comment: When I try `configuration.GetSection("SomeSection").Get<SomeSection>()` it works for some reason with your example.

Comment: Perfect, I was missing the `.Get<SomeSection>`, if you edit your answer with that in it then I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Perfect, marked as answer, cheers. Always the little things :)